# I can't see the original content of my viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I accidentally removed the original screen of my viewport when I clicked the cursor in the split screen view. How can I see the original state of my viewport? The one that has colors because I already added some colors to it and now the one that I'm seeing is the original right screen in the split screen view. The original content(the one that has colors) in the left view is now gone.

[image]

Comment: Click on the circular buttons in the top right of the 3D view.

Comment: Thank you so much dude, I thought I'm in a serious problem... such a big help!